# Can you write code directly into Scene Builder?

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder

Is there a way to create a functioning calculator in JavaFX Scene Builder and completely by-passing Eclipse?

My teacher told me I can only code directly into Scene Builder to build a simple Java calculator project. So far I can do it only by creating a JavaFX project in Eclipse, creating an fxml file through that project, and opening that fxml file through Scene Builder, creating my layout, then writing java controller code by copy/pasting the skeleton code provided by Scene Builder into a java file in Eclipse. My question is: Is there a way to write the controller code directly into Scene Builder?

Comment: No, you cannot—especially since the text area that shows the sample skeleton controller is not editable. I would ask your teacher for clarification because that requirement is _ridiculous_, even if it were possible.

Comment: I will give the teacher the benefit of the doubt and assume they meant you can build the calculator **interface** entirely in SceneBuilder; that much is true. But you cannot make it actually function without writing Java code...

Comment: Theoretically you could add javascript to the fxml (see https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#scripting) but SceneBuilder afaik does not support this and you get rid of all the autocomplete and code checking features an IDE has to offer... (Of course you could tie your hands behind your back, but why not use a simpler approach, especially if you're new to this?)